# Portable.Licensing how to tie a license to a PC

Tags: c#, licensing

We have a C# application and need to protect it against illegal copying. So we decided to use the `Portable.Licensing` library to protect our system.

How I can tie a license to hardware id in `Portable.Licensing`, so that only a specific PC can use license?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can generate a unique hash over the PC's name, hardware information, etc. and add this hash as `Additional Attribute` during the license creation.

Example of license creation:

```
var license = License.New()  
    .WithUniqueIdentifier(Guid.NewGuid())  
    .As(LicenseType.Standard)    
    .WithMaximumUtilization(1)  
    .WithAdditionalAttributes(new Dictionary<string, string>  
                              {  
                                  {"HardwareId", "........"}  
                              })  
    .LicensedTo("John Doe", "john.doe@yourmail.here")  
    .CreateAndSignWithPrivateKey(privateKey, passPhrase);
```

To validate the attribute you can implement your own validation extension method or just use the existing `AssertThat()`. Example: [1]

The generation of a unique hardware id is out of the scope of portable licensing.

[1] https://github.com/dnauck/Portable.Licensing/blob/develop/src/Portable.Licensing/Validation/LicenseValidationExtensions.cs#L100

Comment: How to validate?

Comment: This will require client side license generation (otherwise how do we know the hardware id?). Then anybody will be able to generate a license. Or I’m getting it wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You can call `AsserThat` method:

```
license.Validate()
.AssertThat(lic => lic.ProductFeatures.Get("HardwareId") == "133456", new GeneralValidationFailure() { Message="Invalid Hardware.", HowToResolve="Contact administrator"});
```

Comment: @Shuaib you can write your own logic using the WithMaximumUtilization value when validating the license. Ex: Limit the maximum number of users

Comment: while this code snippet itself can work, i tried to **append** it to    other fluent api, such as in the github [readme](https://github.com/dnauck/Portable.Licensing): `var validationFailures = license.Validate()...(I want put your code here)`, but I always failed compile. could you give your example?

Comment: I finally resolved the errors by adding `Add()` method among different validations. However there's no detailed documents about it.

Answer (score 2):

Use ProtectedData.Protect with DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine to encrypt some key value pair in the licence file. 
Then the Licence is valid only if that value can be successfully decrypted on the same machine.

ProtectedData.UnProtect will only decrypt on the same machine it was encrypted.
This will require desktop/client server interaction during the registration process to implement though.