# Using Portable.Licensing how to validate the attribute hardware Id

Tags: c#, licensing

I am working on certain project. All i need is to provide the license of the product to only one computer so i added an additional attribute hardware Id as shown in fig .How can i validate it. help me out in this regard. Thanks..

```
var license = Portable.Licensing.License.New()
                   .WithUniqueIdentifier(Guid.NewGuid())
                   .As(Portable.Licensing.LicenseType.Trial)
                   .ExpiresAt(DateTime.Now.AddDays(5))
                   .WithMaximumUtilization(Int32.Parse(User.Text))
                   .WithAdditionalAttributes(new Dictionary<String,String>{
                                               {"Hardware ID","12343"}
                                                })
                   .LicensedTo(name.Text, email.Text)
                   .CreateAndSignWithPrivateKey(privateKey, "212555555");
```

Comment: when the app is licensed are you then sending that key back up to one of your databases via the internet?

Comment: and what hardware are you trying to tie the key too?

Comment: Yes I am sending .lic file to database. here hardware is the combination of   cpu id and hard drive id @Simon Price

Comment: why the hdd id? people swap in and out the hdd for all sorts of reasons, using the cpu id is a good idea though. Do you have the code to get the cpu id or do you need that?

Comment: I dont have but will be searching. But my concern is about how to validate hardware ID using Portable.Licensing.

Comment: Please see the answer explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30706365/3581643).

Answer (score 5):

Well I found the answer for this very simple one.

1. Using `AssertThat()` method provided by Portable.Licencing.
   ex:-

   ```
           var validationFailures = licenseContent.Validate()
           .ExpirationDate()
           .When(lic => lic.Type == Portable.Licensing.LicenseType.Trial)
           .And()
           .AssertThat(lic => lic.Quantity >= 3, failure1)
           .And()
           .AssertThat(lic => lic.ProductFeatures.Get("HardwareID") == "133456", failure1)
           .When(lic => lic.ProductFeatures.Contains("HardwareID"))
           .And()
           .Signature(publicKey)
           .AssertValidLicense().ToList();
   ```
2. Write your own validation case.

Comment: is there document of full api usage? such as `When`, `And`, the github readme didn't explain much. the users will need much time to experiment or even check the code.

Comment: I know it's an old thread, but I need to know. What is failure1?